# How to make a loop of rectangles filled with various color?

Tags: javascript, p5.js

```
for(let i=0;i<10;i++){
       rect(10+40*i,160,30,30)  
    }
```

I make various of rect on my code, the thing I want to do is to give these rectangles many color but not repeating and followed color order.

Thanks for help :]

Comment: Create an array of colors and index into it to get a color for `fill()` which you can call before `rect()` in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript fillRect() method
eg:

```
ctx.fillRect(x,y,width,height);
```

In this syntax:

x is the x-axis coordinate of the starting point of the rectangle.
y is the y-axis coordinate of the starting point of the rectangle.
width is the rectangles’ width. It can be positive or negative. The positive values are to the right while the negative values are to the left.
height is the rectangle’s height. It can be also positive or negative. The positive values are down while the negative values are up.

Comment: OP is using p5.js so it should be `fill()` and `rect()`. This doesn't really answer the question of how to change the color in any case.